# Shimano MTB (SM-SH51) Cleats moving vertically in pedal

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, cleat

My new shoes/cleats seem to have "vertical" movement (not lateral float) and I can't figure out why, or how to fix it.

I recently got new shoes (Shimano XC-7) that use the same SM-SH51 standard Shimano cleat that I have been using until now in my old Giro shoes (probably 3 years on the old shoes/cleats). Same pedals, same set up, but if I pull up on my foot, I can create a clear gap between the shoe and the pedal - it isn't disengaging or coming out (i.e. I'm not unclipping). There is definitely a little more float than w/ the Giro shoes, but I can't tell why.

There are no shims under the cleats that I can see (unless they're inside the shoe, under the foot bed, but that shouldn't interfere w/ how the pedal interacts w/ the sole of the shoe).

Any ideas what causes this or how to fix it? It's a bit disorienting; I will probably be able to get used to just tweaking my pedal stroke, but that seems not optimal.

Comment: I am guessing that the cleat recess in the shoes is shallower than the cleat design expects.

Comment: I have/had the same issue. At first I found it very annoying and made a thin metal shim to completely eliminate the play. Then I had knee issues from pulling on the pedals. By now I don’t think that pulling on the pedals is a good idea. Your legs are not meant to apply force in that direction and I’m not sure it has any benefits regarding total power output or efficiency. I recall a study of professional riders where it turned out that they didn’t pull on their pedals at all.

Comment: @Michael Pulling on pedals is helpful in short very steep sections and in sprints. But the vertical play is annoying even with just pulling with a very little force, even so small that it could only raise the cleat and not the pedal.

Comment: @VladimirF: There is lots of controversy around the topic.

Comment: What pedal or pedals?

Comment: Clarifying note - the pedals are Shimano PD-A520's; worked great on the old shoe/cleat combo. With regard to whether it's good/bad to pull up, I notice it mostly if I'm trying to do a lot of hamstring-focused pedaling as part of intervals (advised by a coach and physical therapist to do so to help w/ additional muscle engagement). Not trying to debate the merits of pedaling style - just trying to get the play out of the cleat/pedal interface.